# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen »Variable« und »Veränderliche«?

Tags: difference, noun

Wie der Titel schon sagt, will ich wissen, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen »Variable« und »Veränderliche« gibt.

- In Wikipedia führt beides auf den Artikel »Variable« ([Link](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver%C3%A4nderliche)).
- Der Duden führt "Variable" als Synonym zu »Veränderliche« ([Link](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Veraenderliche)).

<sub>Ich frage trotzdem, weil ich bisher noch kein *echtes* Synonym gefunden habe und es mich überraschen würde, hier eines zu haben.</sub>

»Veränderliche« hört man seltener, aber gibt es sonst noch einen Bedeutungsunterschied oder einen Unterschied in der Verwendung?

Comment: Bzgl. "echte" Synonyme. Im Prinzip hast du Recht. Manchmal bedeuten Wörter aber exakt das Selbe, ist das eine Wort nur zum Beispiel formeller, Beamtendeutsch oder wird vor Gericht verwendet, während das andere Umgangssprache, Slang oder sonstiges ist. Das trifft hier natürlich nicht zu. Hier ist - wie meine Antwort besagt - das eine Wort das *deutsche Wort* und das andere *das eingedeutsche*, wenngleich ich mich mit so einer Aussage auch auf einem schmalen Grat bewege ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Der Duden nennt eine [Variable](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Variable) *eine veränderliche Größe*. *Variable* kommt vom lateinischen *varius*, das so viel bedeutet wie: *verschieden*. Beide Wörter *Variable* und *Veränderliche* sind substantivierte Adjektive. Ersteres wird insbesondere in der Mathematik und in der Physik verwendet, aber auch bei der Programmierung. In all den Zusammenhängen hört man äußerst selten *Veränderliche*. Offen gestanden, ich kann mich gar nicht erinnern, es schon mal als Nomen gehört zu haben. Das zeigt auch, dass der Duden die Häufigkeit von *Variable* höher einschätzt als die von *Veränderliche*.

*Veränderlich* wird in der Regel als Adjektiv verwendet, zum Beispiel *ein veränderlicher Wert* oder *[veränderliche Sterne](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver%C3%A4nderlicher_Stern)* (wobei auch hier die alternative Namensgebung *variable Sterne* genannt wird).

Diese beiden Wörter sind also in der Tat synonym, und aus der Lamäng heraus wüsste ich kein Beispiel, wo man die Wörter nicht nach Belieben austauschen darf. Als Nomen klingt jedoch *Veränderliche* zumeist ungewohnt.

---

Das ngram zeigt, dass vor vielen, vielen Jahren mal das Wort *Veränderliche* verwendet wurde, hingegen *Variable* noch nicht existierte (im Deutschen). Mit der Zeit etablierte sich *Variable*, während die Verwendung von *Veränderliche* gegen null konvergiert.

[image]

Auch als Adjektiv wurde *veränderlich* mit der Zeit durch *variabel* abgelöst.

[image]

Comment: schöne Antwort :-) Besonders das ngramm gefällt mir. Du meinst sicher `Veränderliche` und nicht `Verschiedene`, oder?

Comment: @moose Ja, richtig. Hab mich von dem Satz davor beeinflussen lassen ;)

Comment: "aus der Lamäng heraus wüsste ich kein Beispiel, wo man die Wörter nicht nach Belieben austauschen darf."
Ein Gegenbeispiel wo der Austausch zu Verwirrung führen könnte ist die funktionale Programmiersprache Haskell. Hier ist mir bisher nur der Begriff "Variable" und nicht "Veränderliche" untergekommen. Variable meint hier jedoch etwas unveränderliches, das, einmal bestimmt, nicht mehr geändert werden kann. Würde man nun anfangen statt Variable Veränderliche zu sagen würde man Gefahr laufen den Eindruck erwecken, dass eine Variable doch veränderlich (oder variabel ;)) sei.

Comment: @efie Hm. Dann ist Haskell blöde ;) Immerhin sind *Variablen* die man nicht verändern kann eigentlich *Konstanten* :D

Comment: @Em1: Du kannst in objektorientierten Programmiersprachen auch ein Objekt wie "Student" haben, welcher einen Namen hat, und zwar für jeden Studenten einen unterschiedlichen, aber nachdem einmal fixiert, fortan unveränderlich. Dagegen ist math.PI eine echte Konstante.

Comment: @userunknown Womit du mich an einen Artikel aus der dotnetpro erinnerst, in dem es um den Unterschied zw. den Schlüsselwörter const und readonly geht. Und wie ich gerade sehe, lautet die Überschrift "Veränderliche Konstanten". :) Der Unterschied ist übrigens. const = konstant. Basta. (Sprich: public const double pi = 3.14;) Aber readonly ist das, was du hier für den Student beschreibst, also man kann den Wert bei der Deklaration selbst oder im Konstruktor festlegen.

Comment: Die Mondphasen kann ich nicht verändern, sie sind aber dennoch ziemlich variabel. :-) Ich kenne mich mit Haskell nicht aus, aber in C++ kann man ein Argument als konstant definieren, dann kann man es in der Funktion nicht ändern, aber es kann natürlich trotzdem bei jedem Aufruf einen anderen Wert haben. Dasselbe gilt auch für lokale konstante Variablen, die mit nicht-konstanten Werten initialisiert werden. Ach ja, und dann wäre da noch `const volatile`, das wohl am besten dem Mondphasen-Beispiel entspricht.

Comment: @celtschk In C++ muss man vor allen Dingen noch darauf achten, ob man den Wert oder die Adresse als const definiert. - Wie auch immer, die Sprachen bieten alle einen unterschiedlichen Ansatz. Mein Statement, dass Haskell "blöde" ist, war auch nur ironisch. Habe nie mit der Sprache gearbeitet, kann mir also kein Urteil erlauben.

Comment: Ach ja, noch was: was ist eine Lamäng?

Comment: @celtschk [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lamäng); "etwas aus dem Stegreif / unvorbereitet / routiniert machen; etwas ohne Vorüberlegung tun " --> hier also: Ich hab das auf die Schnelle so gesagt, ohne tiefgründige Reserche oder weiterführende Gedankensammlung.

Comment: In Wendungen wie „Differentialrechnung einer Veränderlichen“ kommt die Veränderliche noch regelmäßig vor, gerne auch in Buchtiteln.

Answer (score 6):

In der Mathematik und Physik sind *Variable* und *Veränderliche* Synonyme, wobei *Veränderliche* eher ungebräuchlich geworden ist, aber noch immer vorkommt.

(z.B: [Trennung der Veränderlichen auf Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trennung_der_Ver%C3%A4nderlichen))

In der Informatik habe ich *Veränderliche* noch nie gehört, hier herrscht *Variable* vor.

Ich habe auch den Eindruck, dass die meisten Informatiker und Programmierer das Wort nicht mehr als substantiviertes Adjektiv deklinieren – also Dativ Singular *der Variable* statt *der Variablen*:

> In dieser Programmzeile wird der Variable *x* ein neuer Wert zugewiesen.