# Gibt es echte Synonyme?

Tags: synonym

Gibt es in der deutschen Sprache echte Synonyme? Soweit ich es bisher aus meinen Recherchen sehen konnte, haben selbst die naheliegendsten Ausdrücke immer noch verschiedene Nuancen oder Konnotationen.

Beispiele:

- [Unterschied zwischen »des Nachts«, »nachts«, »bei Nacht« und »in der Nacht«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23639/16019)
- [Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen »froh« und »fröhlich«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5821/16019)
- [Der Unterschied zwischen »verfaulen« und »verwesen«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/21948/16019)
- u.v.a.

Nicht umsonst gab es vielleicht deswegen das »[Synonymische Handwörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](http://www.textlog.de/synonym.html)«.

Eine Möglichkeit echter Synonyme sind aus meiner Sicht vielleicht Eindeutschungen, wie zum Beispiel:

- [Ist »Rechner« oder »Computer« korrekt?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23739/16019)
- [Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen »Variable« und »Veränderliche«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4952/16019)
- u.v.a.

Aber nochmals die Frage: gibt es (praktisch oder theoretisch) echte, deutsche Synonyme?

Comment: Die Frage (auf Englisch) bei Linguistics.SE, für beliebige Sprachen: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/do-absolute-synonyms-exist Kurz gesagt, nein, oder wenn, dann nur für sehr kurze Zeit, bevor sie sich auseinanderentwickeln. Ein Spezialfall wären regionale Ausdrücke, wie _Samstag_ und _Sonnabend_; die können wirklich dasselbe bedeuten, werden aber von unterschiedlichen Leuten benutzt.

Comment: @chirlu: Das solltest du als Antwort schreiben, nicht als Kommentar.

Comment: @chirlu: Außerdem sind gerade *Samstag* und *Sonnabend* ein gutes Beispiel für echte Synonyme. Ich kenne nämlich durchaus Leute, die beides benutzen und naturgemäß gibt es bei diesen Wörtern eben keine Bedeutungsnuancen, die zu einem Unterschied führen können.

Comment: Samstag/Sonnabend halte ich in jedem Fall für wasserdicht. Aber mir fehlt eine präzise Definition, was "echte Synonyme" sein sollen. Oma/Großmutter und Opa/Großvater z.B. haben aus meiner Sicht exakt die gleiche Bedeutung, aber Oma/Opa gebrauche ich bevorzugt im familiären Kontext. Sind das dann noch "echte Synonyme"?

Answer (score 8):

Gerade das Deutsche hat sich ein paar wahrlich echte Synonyme bewahrt. Dass diese Ausdrücke meistens regional unterschiedlich verwendet werden, hat für die Frage, ob es Synonyme sind, keine Auswirkungen.

- *Samstag* versus *Sonnabend*. Es ist ein Tag gemeint, der ist klar definiert.
- *Spitzer* und *Anspitzer*. Der Gegenstand, der Bleistifte *spitzt* oder *anspitzt* – sowohl der Gegenstand als auch die Tätigkeit sind klar definiert.

Damit wäre bewiesen, dass es echte Synonyme gibt.

---

Eine weitergehende Teilantwort, die sehr wenig mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat: Auch in anderen Sprachen existieren echte Synonyme. Im Finnischen gibt es die beiden Begrüßungs- und Verabschiedungswörter *moi* und *hei*. Die beiden sind absolut identisch in ihrer Verwendung. Wer mit dem einen grüßt, kann mit dem anderen den Gruß erwidert bekommen oder mit dem gleichen. Sogar regionale Vorlieben oder das Alter der Grüßenden spielt keine Rolle.

Im erweiterten Kontext könnte man noch *moikka* dazunehmen; das ist allerdings eher ein Diminutiv von *moi*.

Außerdem beliebt sind die Wörter, die in den verschiedenen Varietäten des Englischen unterschiedlich verwendet werden: So sind *caravan* (US) und *motor home* (UK) ebenfalls Synonyme, die sich nur in der verwendeten Varietät unterscheiden.

Comment: Geldbeutel / Portemonnaie fällt mir spontan noch ein.

Comment: @Matthias Hab ich schon im Anschlag gehabt und dann wieder weggelöscht, weil ich mir nicht sicher war.

Comment: Du meinst, ein Paar reicht ja für den Existenzbeweis, und jedes weitere vergrößert nur die Gefahr von Spitzfindigkeiten? ;-)

Comment: @Matthias nein, es ist mir eher darum gegangen, dass es Leute gibt, die mit mittelalterlichen Lederbeuteln am Gürtel rumlaufen, die man auch als *Geldbeutel* bezeichnen könnte, aber wo ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob es *Portmonee* auch trifft ;)

Comment: Wenn diese Leute die Frage "Hast Du Dein Portemonnaie dabei" mit "Ja" beantworten würden, dann schon. Wobei wir aber schon wieder bei der Frage wären, woran man "echte Synonyme" erkennt.

Comment: Ich würde noch *selbstständig/selbständig* als Beispiel vorschlagen. Die meisten Leute halten den Unterschied (fälschlicherweise) für eine Frage der Rechtschreibung.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Damit sagst du, dass Duden einen Fehler begeht, denn die deklarieren es nur als alternative Rechtschreibung.

Comment: @Em1: Gewissermaßen ([Begründung](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/8126/2594)). Andererseits kann ich die Deklaration als alternative Rechtschreibung in einem Rechtschreibwörterbuch nachvollziehen, da es eben perfekte Synonyme sind (was ich allerdings unsinnig fand, war das alte Verhalten des Dudens, *selbstständig* für orthografisch falsch zu erklären).